# Type macro are dead : how can i compute a type from a definition?

Tags: scala, types, compilation, scala-macros, dynamic-compilation

Type macros are off.

However I have two important use cases that would have required them. The result is an important lost of extensibility in my application.
Both are dynamic compile time generation of a type given other types.
Basically i want to do something like (obviously not scala code but i think you'll get the idea) :

```
type T[U] = macro usecase1[U]

def usecase1[U]= U match {  
  case t if (t <:< Int) => String
  case ... => ...
}
```

Second use case is :

```
type Remaining[A, B >: A] = macro ...
```

where for example

```
class C
trait T1 extends C
trait T2 extends C

type Remaining[C with T1 with T2, T2] is assigned to "C with T1" at compile time
(so the macro would have generated the subclass list, and generated a new type from the list without T2)
```

I didn't do it with macros so that are assumptions. I planned to do it now.. till i saw that type macro were dead. 
Anyway, did anyone knows a trick to obtain such functionalities?
Thanks

Comment: In your first example you do not show the _usecase_ but the macro definition. Without the actual use case (where is `T[U]` needed) it's difficult to assess. It looks, though, as you don't need macros here but just some type constraints which may work out of the box.

Comment: Types in scala are very flexible. See scalaz and shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless‎) for advanced type usages.

Comment: @0__ The second use case is to do something like : [link](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.fr/2009/09/type-safe-builder-in-scala-part-4.html), however with complex options, e.g. "if i plug option A, i cannot plug B; D become plugable after having plugged C etc". I ended up with something like in the link, however, instead of having a short readeable code with pattern case, I end up with writing exhaustively all the tree across child classes. The first use case is an automatic conversion. Once again i can do it with a simple algorithm, but I have to write all the cases in different classes.

Comment: @Arseniy Zhizhelev It seems not to do what I want (or I didn't understand them). I understand there is two distinct worlds in scala. The world of identified elements and the world of types. You can code in the world of identified element but only statistically declare in the world of type. My dream would have been to code in the world of type (using only types), but it seems to be a dead dream..

Comment: @coo-lhobou The article Type-Level Programming in Scala (http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) shows that the type system is rather powerful and allows almost general programming! I can't see what you want to achieve. Could you explain the problem without macros?

Comment: @Arseniy Zhizhelev Thank you for this link I will start by carefully reading it. I'm sure I will learn several things at least

Comment: @Coo LHibou Could you elaborate on the first use case by showing an example of how you would use T[U]? This is something for which implicits / implicit macros might be very helpful.

Comment: @Coo LHibou The dream of living in the world of types isn't that dead. In Scala we have implicits that bridge the two worlds.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Thanks to Aseniy Zhizhelev link, I step forward with my issue. I learn how to use HList and I indeed better understand implicit advantages by studying shapeless code. I came up with another implementation of my first use case that you can find here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006363/scala-type-manipulation-at-type-level-something-is-going-wrong) . I'm still stuck. And I do not see how to use implicit here : if I pass instanciated parameters I will have to pass e.g implicit Remover for FooI, implicit Folder for FooII etc and that will break my class hierarchy!

Comment: @EugeneBurmako the aforementioned link as been updated with a (not working) example with implicits

Answer (score 1):

The first use case is indeed implementable with implicits to some degree, as far as I understand it. Here's an example of how this might look like:

```
scala> trait Bound[A] {
     |   type Type
     | }
defined trait Bound

scala> implicit val bound1 = new Bound[Int] { type Type = String }
bound1: Bound[Int]{type Type = String}

scala> implicit val bound2 = new Bound[String] { type Type = Double }
bound2: Bound[String]{type Type = Double}

scala> val tpe = implicitly[Bound[Int]]
tpe: Bound[Int] = $anon$1@2a6b3a99

scala> type U = tpe.Type
defined type alias U
```

But then:

```
scala> implicitly[U =:= String]
<console>:19: error: Cannot prove that U =:= String.
              implicitly[U =:= String]
                        ^
```

On the other hand:

```
scala> implicitly[bound1.Type =:= String]
res0: =:=[bound1.Type,String] = <function1>
```

Implicit resolution seems to be losing some types on the way. Not sure why, and how to work around that.

---

For the second use case, `HList`s immediately come to mind. Something like:

```
scala> trait Remaining[A <: HList, B] { type Result = Remove[A, B] }
defined trait Remaining

scala> new Remaining[C :: T1 :: T2 :: HNil, T2] {}
res5: Remaining[shapeless.::[C,shapeless.::[T1,shapeless.::[T2,shapeless.HNil]]],T2] = $anon$1@3072e54b
```

Not sure how to combine the resulting `HList` into a compound type though. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
trait Remaining[A <: HList, B] {
  def produceType(
    implicit ev0 : Remove.Aux[A, B, C],
             ev1 : IsCons.Aux[C, H, T],
             ev2 : LeftFolder[T, H, (T1, T2) => T1 with T2]) = ev2
             //                     ^ Not real syntax, type-level function to combine/mix types
  val tpe = produceType
  type Result = tpe.Out
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I don't have acces to a scala compiler but I guess
`type U = tpe.type#Type`
would not loose the information